# Are pure sheaves actually vector bundles on projective curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves

A coherent sheaf is *pure* if every non-trivial coherent subsheaf has the same dimension, where the dimension of a sheaf is the dimension of its support.

As in the title, I wonder if the notion of pure sheaves and that of vector bundles coincide on projective curves. If not how about *smooth* projective curves *over $\mathbb C$*?

Any reference about pure sheaves are also welcome.

Comment: you can check of something is a vectorbundle or not locally, and evey local ring of a smooth curve is a p.i.d and using structure theorem of modules over a p.i.d you can see that the localisation of a pure sheaf is free.

Comment: If the curve is singular, this is false: if $\pi :\tilde{C}\rightarrow C $ is the normalization, $\pi _*\mathscr{O}_{\tilde{C} }$ is a pure sheaf which is not locally free.

Comment: Any 0-dimensional sheaf is pure and not a vector bundle.